# Issues with Petrel and ILMerge'd dll's

Tags: ocean, petrel

I have built a plugin that has a number of dll's.  When running this with Petrel 2012.5 it works fine with no issues.  However after using ILMerge on the same dll's and then running in Petrel  with the merged dll I now get InvalidOperationException's (Workspace not yet opened).  Has anybody else had this issue?

Comment: Are you merging the Ocean libraries into yours ?

Comment: the ocean libraries are referenced by my merged dll's but are not merged in.  Using fuslogvw I don't see any errors about missing dll's so I'm assuming ILMerge adds these references to the new merged dll?

Comment: Got your request through our Support team. We are working on it right now

Comment: @user1584120 Looks like your Module class is missing